# Android GPS map shows grid

Tags: android, android-mapview

After 30 hours of programming and failing at this, I realised I couldn't do what I wanted. So this is a last ditch effort to score a pass.

Trying to implement google api to show stuff on a map.

I've basically followed the Android tutorial entirely and it still refuses to work.

It just shows the grid on the MapView, my friend tested my api key so it should be fine.

The only permission I was supposed to use is

```
android.permission.INTERNET
```

I've seen the other thread, but I'm positive the key is fine and I think the permission is in the right place.

```
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="key"
   />


 </LinearLayout>
```

manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
```

import java.util.List;

```
 import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;


import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends MapActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
    MyItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable);

    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");

    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
 }



@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
     }
```

seems I was premature, I built another key, exactly as I did last time. This time the key worked.

but now the problem is, when I click on zoom, it force closes teh application

Comment: are you using a release API key with an APK signed in debug mode?

Comment: I have no idea what that means. I'm using the api key I got after pasting an MD5 to here: http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html.  I've tried my friends api too and it didn't work either, but both work for him. I think its just a debug one generated by an api, I remember doing it all through cmd

Comment: 1.  When you produced your key, did you use your application specific `.keystore file`? or did you use the android `debug.keystore`?  2.  When you run the application to test it, are you exporting a release APK signed with your `.keystore` or are you just producing a debug build?  It looks like you have a mismatched API for the APK you are testing on.

Comment: I got it from the debug keystore

Comment: besides, if the key works for a friend on his own program, not mine, how could it be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use `debug.keystore`. Use `new keystore`. `Right click on ur project>Android tools> Export signed application package`. Create new keystore (Remember alias name and password).

Now use following command in command prompt:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin


keytool -v -list -alias <ur alias name> -keystore <ur keystore name>.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

It asks for `password` later it gives a `MD5 fingerprint` Use that md5 fingerprint to generate  `google api key`. Replace the key.
Now `Project Right Click>Android tools>Export Signed Application package>`

```
Use existing keystore
```

select previous keystore and u `get apk in release mode.` check installing this apk.It should run properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem with your MyItemizedOverlay class only.

You mentioned **when i click on zoom** means **zoom controls** or on your **android marker** ??

I tested my code as you did but only the change is my own ItemizedOverlay class. its working fine for both zoom controls and marker click.

The only thing i can help you is, **if your app crashed when you click marker on map, then you have to pass the Context to ItemizedOverlay class**

If not, send your code i will try to solve your problem.